# Writing log from Python to Mongo DB

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, mongodb-query, apscheduler

I am trying to write log from Python to Mongo DB. My code is executing and creating Database as 'DSLogSummary' but not writing entries to collection:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pymongo import ASCENDING
from pytz import utc
import datetime

client = MongoClient()
db = client.DSLogSummary
collection = db.ds_jobLogEntry
collection.ensure_index([("timestamp", ASCENDING)])

def log(msg):
    entry = {}
    entry['timestamp'] = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    entry['msg'] = msg
    collection_id = collection.insert_one(entry).inserted_id

def job_test():
    print ("Hello World")
    log('Job executed')

jobstores = {
     'mongo': {'type': 'mongodb'},
}

sched = BlockingScheduler()
sched.configure(jobstores=jobstores, timezone=utc)
sched.add_job(job_test, trigger='cron', month='*', hour='*', minute = '*', second='*/5')
sched.start()
```

Output is: 
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World

[image]

Comment: Your code works properly, entries are visible in the collection !

Answer (score -2):

Your code works properly, entries are visible in the collection...

---

According to your use case -*writing log*- in my opinion you will better when using a time-serie oriented database more than MongoDB database. [no-sql DB]

*By using MongoDB you will take the risk that events visible inside the DB will no reflect the reality because the async write of the data.*

You may take a look [here](https://blog.timescale.com/how-to-store-time-series-data-mongodb-vs-timescaledb-postgresql-a73939734016) and [here](https://blog.timescale.com/time-series-data-why-and-how-to-use-a-relational-database-instead-of-nosql-d0cd6975e87c) to know why MongoDb is not good for timeseries...

In your case, [InfluxDB](https://www.influxdata.com/) is maybe a better choice (or [Mysql](https://www.mysql.com/))

Comment: this is not answering the question.